# output with Header in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am running a Batch file using powershell and then do Little post processing to extract an ID from it. so far so good but i also would like to see it with Header.

```
$TempCIID = ci-list.bat -node_list server.domain.local | Select-String -pattern "ID: "
```

Output of this line is - ID: bbeaf351b2b071c35f3f984af5a15c2e

then post processing as shown below.

```
$CIID = $TempCIID -split("ID: ");
$CIID = $CIID.Trim();
```

as a result i have.

```
bbeaf351b2b071c35f3f984af5a15c2e
```

where the desired Output is:

```
ID
---
bbeaf351b2b071c35f3f984af5a15c2e
```

I have tried different Format cmdlet(s) but nothing helps.

any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your string parts into a custom object property/value pair. If you split by `:` and trim the leading/trailing spaces, you will have an array that includes your property as the first element (`[0]`) and value as the second element (`[1]`).

```
# Assuming $TempCIID contains the following
$TempCIID = 'ID: bbeaf351b2b071c35f3f984af5a15c2e'

$CIID = $TempCIID.Split(':').Trim()
[pscustomobject]@{$CIID[0] = $CIID[1]}

# Output 

ID
--
bbeaf351b2b071c35f3f984af5a15c2e
```

---

If you require your output to be a string and want more flexibility with your output, I recommend using the format operator (`-f`).

```
$CIID = $TempCIID.Split(':').Trim()
"{0}`n---`n{1}" -f $CIID[0],$CIID[1]

# Output

ID
---
bbeaf351b2b071c35f3f984af5a15c2e
```

Comment: Thanks. i want this as object only.